# Porting PHP decryption AES-256-CBC to C#

Tags: c#, php, encryption

i have the following PHP decryption routine which is working flawlessly and need help converting it to c#. i have tried many approaches but none of them is working.
i have managed to match the hash function output between c# and php. 
also matched the output of the conversion from and to base64.

PHP Code:

```
function decrypt($encrypted_txt, $secret_key, $secret_iv)
{
$encrypt_method = "AES-256-CBC";
// hash
$key = hash('sha256', $secret_key);
// iv - encrypt method AES-256-CBC expects 16 bytes - else you will get a warning
$iv = substr(hash('sha256', $secret_iv), 0, 16);
$output = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($encrypted_txt), $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
return $output;
}
```

> ```
> secret_key= "t-3zafRa"; 
> secret_key_hash = "d03a4d94b29e7f55c80726f1152dcebc9f03f4c698470f72083af967cf786b6b";
> ```
>
> the problem is that the key hash is a 64 bytes which is invalid for the AES-256 but i am not sure how it's working in php and how the openssl_decrypt php function is dealing with the keys.

i have also tried to pass the MD5 of the key hash but also failed to decrypt.

```
byte[] asciiBytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(keyhash);
byte[] hashedBytes = MD5CryptoServiceProvider.Create().ComputeHash(asciiBytes);
string keymd5 = BitConverter.ToString(hashedBytes).Replace("-", "").ToLower(); //To match with PHP MD5 output
```

C# Hashing function:

```
static string sha256(string randomString)
        {
            var crypt = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed();
            var hash = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            byte[] crypto = crypt.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(randomString));
            foreach (byte theByte in crypto)
            {
                hash.Append(theByte.ToString("x2"));
            }
            return hash.ToString();
        }
```

C# Decryption routine:

```
static string DecryptStringFromBytesAes(byte[] cipherText, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
        {
            // Check arguments.
            if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
            if (key == null || key.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
            if (iv == null || iv.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("iv");

            // Declare the RijndaelManaged object
            // used to decrypt the data.
            RijndaelManaged aesAlg = null;

            // Declare the string used to hold
            // the decrypted text.
            string plaintext;

            // Create a RijndaelManaged object
            // with the specified key and IV.
           aesAlg = new RijndaelManaged { Mode = CipherMode.CBC, Padding = PaddingMode.None, KeySize = 256, BlockSize = 128, Key = key, IV = iv };

            // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
            ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);
            // Create the streams used for decryption.
            using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
            {
                using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                    {
                        // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream
                        // and place them in a string.
                        plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                        srDecrypt.Close();
                    }
                }
            }

            return plaintext;
        }
```

any help or ideas are highly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think the key is 64 bytes? It looks like 32 to me.

Comment: Note that hexadecimal encoding uses _two_ characters per byte, so if you encode a 32-byte key in hex it will result in a 64-character string.

Comment: Your padding is incorrect, however. `openssl_decrypt` by default uses PKCS#7-padding, but in C# you've disabled padding altogether. You need to set `Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7`.

Answer (score 3):

`openssl_decrypt` simply takes as many bytes for the key as required for the algorithm. As your algorithm is "AES-256-CBC" is uses 32 bytes (256 bits), as AES-256 is defined to as AES with a 256 bit key (and 14 rounds, rather than 10 or 12).

The way PHP does this is either by adding `00` valued bytes to the right in case the key is too small, or - as in your case - by simply ignoring the bytes after the 32st one. That's not a good way to behave of any kind of cryptographic library, especially for a high level language like PHP, but the OpenSSL wrapper library does it anyway.

So you have to extract the first 32 bytes from the hex encoded key and use that as key in C# to be compatible. Using different hash functions is of course not going to work, MD5 and SHA-256 are entirely incompatible (by design). Of course, you now have 16 hex encoded bytes left, which means you are using AES-256 with 128 bit keys, leaving you with 128 bit security. And yes, you need to use PKCS#7 padding in C#.

---

Note that using CBC with a static IV is not secure. Using CBC mode for transport mode security is not secure. Using SHA-256 or any normal hash over a password or key with little entropy is not secure. Storing keys in strings is generally not secure.

Getting crypto working is hard enough; getting it secure is much harder and requires understanding what the heck you're doing in the first place. You need to start off with a good protocol for your specific use case (and that's skipping a few steps already).